# What is the meaning of "quinda" in a song by José Afonso?

Tags: significado

In this song: [Canção de embalar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8TpRnMU09M) we have this verse:

> Dorme quinda à noite é uma menina

I do not understand what is the subject of "è" and what "quinda" means - I found this: ["Espécie de cesto cylíndrico, sem tampa."](https://www.lexico.pt/pesquisa.php?q=quinda) but
I do not see how it would be related to the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *"quinda"*, or even better *"qu'inda"*, is simply the contraction of *que* + *ainda* (for instance, [see here](https://psicod.org/ser-protagonista--lngua-portuguesa-v4.html?page=160)).

Thus, this gives us:

> Dorme que ainda a noite é uma menina (sleep, for the night is still a child)

By the way, despite most websites with lyrics showing *"à noite"* that's wrong, it should be just *"a noite"*.

By far the most famous appearance of *"qu'inda"* is in [*Canção do exílio*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_Ex%C3%ADlio), by Gonçalves Dias:

> Minha terra tem palmeiras,
> Onde canta o Sabiá;
> As aves, que aqui gorjeiam,
> Não gorjeiam como lá.
>
> [...]
>
> Sem qu'inda aviste as palmeiras,
> Onde canta o Sabiá.

Comment: Gerardo, *quinda* is actually a mispelling: the correct spelling is *q'inda*. And [inda (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/inda) is a word, not a contraction. In fact, Houaiss says *inda* is the original, and *ainda* was formed after it.